# How to set resource limits for init on boot?

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system, system-calls

I'm trying to find a way to set the rlimit value for the init process during the boot time. Normally, rlimit is set by calling the "setrlimit" system call.

So I was wondering is there any way to call a system call in the boot time (like calling it in the shell script)? Or, is there any other way to perform equivalent operation of setrlimit?

Comment: Are you sure you want to setrlimit on `init` itself and not the services it starts?

Comment: I know it sounds improper, but yes I think it okay in this specific case. If I can't find a way to do it, I'll setrlimit on the services instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux you can use the `prlimit` syscall/utility to set resource limits for other processes:

```
prlimit — get and set process resource limits
prlimit [options] [ −−resource [=limits] ] [ −−pid PID ]
```

and

```
int prlimit(pid_t pid, int resource, const struct rlimit *new_limit,
            struct rlimit *old_limit);
```

You can run this on boot however you want, such as in `/etc/rc.local` or equivalent, or `@reboot` in crontab if supported.